# How can I give selectors implicit scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written an event handler that detects a change in a select option list and then modifies a few sibling inputs based on the selected value.

I now want to generalise this functionality so that I can use several groups of (driving-select-option-lists + siblings) concurrently. The new onChange handler might look like this:

```
$('.select-list').on('change', handleChange);
```

And the method something like this:

```
function handleChange(event){
  $parent = $(event.delegateTarget).closest('.parent');
  var parentId = '#' + $parent.attr('id');

  $(parentId + '.foo').flyAway();
  $(parentId + '.bar').destroy();
  $(parentId + '.bax').render();
  $(parentId + '.qux').doAGiggy();
  $(parentId + '.lorem').applyPerfume();
  $(parentId + '.ipsum').eatBetter();
  // ... several times
}
```

I would prefer not to repeat the `parentId` part throughout the handler as it's messy and tough to maintain. Is there a way to give my selectors implicit scope i.e. `$('.a-class')` knows which `parent-id` I expect it to "work" within?

Comment: That code is invalid and doesn't do a thing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Who the hell upvotes this stuff?

Comment: Apologies, the handler is not important. I've changed the post - what's important is that I do not want to repeat the `parentId` in the selector. I'd rather have each selector "understand" the context since it's shared. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you delegate event (as it is suggested by the use on .on()) with the following code:

```
$('.parent-container').on('change', '.select-list', handleChange);
```

The event object has [delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) property.

> Description: The element where the currently-called jQuery event handler was attached.

So you could do:

```
function handleChange(event){

  $(event.delegateTarget).find('.a-class').doStuff();
  // .. now use a similar selector $(parentId + ..) several times
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this info did really help me make the code work a bit more nicely. What my (badly phrased question) really is, is there any way I don't have to repeat the `parentId` part of the selector. My edited example is above if you need more info.

Comment: Indeed, the question is just completely different now ;-)

Comment: Something like `$(parentId).find('.a-class, .a-class1, .a-class2, .a-class3').doStuff();` (you should consider using something different than "class1", "class2"... makes it useless to select by class.

Comment: I changed it again, I think it's getting better:) I'm using pseudocode and I think that's where a lot of the confusion is coming from, anyway... the action on each $(parentId + '.child-selector) is different too, that's why I can't chain. Otherwise that would've been the perfect solution.

Comment: Then you can use [.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) - `$(parentId).find('.foo').flyAway().end().find('.bar').destroy()...` - assuming your methods return jquery. Otherwise you're stucked doing the way it is.

Comment: Aha! I think you've hit the nail on the head. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can scope jQuery selectors by passing the parent as the second argument to the `$` function:

```
$('.a-class', parent).doStuff();
$('.another-class', parent).doOtherStuff();
```